# Get different Values in Python Windows and Python OSX

Tags: python

i have a problem, i have a project for the University and i get different values when i run my Mac version of python compiler and the Windows version of the python compiler.

Python version : 2.7
Libraries : Numpy

any clues ?

p161 and pNUMBER are arrays with [0,1,2] coordinates in numpy
The code I have:

```
#PASO 38
print OPCION
print "PASO 38 - ESTRUCTURA DE COSTOS TOTALES POR PRODUCTO [ DATOS EXPRESADOS EN PORCENTAJES DEL COSTO TOTAL DEL PRODUCTO ]"
print
paso38517=numpy.array([100*p161[0]/p351[0],100*p231[0]/p351[0],100*p301[0]/p351[0]])
paso38525=numpy.array([100*p161[1]/p351[1],100*p231[1]/p351[1],100*p301[1]/p351[1]])
paso38535=numpy.array([100*p161[2]/p351[2],100*p231[2]/p351[2],100*p301[2]/p351[2]])

print     "TIPO              517    525    535"
print     "_____________________________________"
print str("MATERIA PRIMA   : ")+ numpy.array_str(paso38517[0])+str("%    ")+numpy.array_str(paso38525[0])+str("%    ")+numpy.array_str(paso38535[0])+str("%")
print str("MANO DE OBRA    : ")+ numpy.array_str(paso38517[1])+str("%    ")+numpy.array_str(paso38525[1])+str("%    ")+numpy.array_str(paso38535[1])+str("%")
print str("USO DE MAQUINA  : ")+ numpy.array_str(paso38517[2])+str("%     ")+numpy.array_str(paso38525[2])+str("%     ")+numpy.array_str(paso38535[2])+str("%")
print     "_____________________________________"
print
#PASO 39
paso39=numpy.array([100*mp1/costofinal,100*mo1/costofinal,100*um1/costofinal])
print OPCION
print "PASO 39 - ESTRUCTURA DE COSTOS TOTAL [ DATOS EXPRESADOS EN PORCENTAJES DE LOS COSTOS TOTALES ]"
print
print     "TIPO                COSTO"
print     "____________________________"
print str("MATERIA PRIMA   : ")+ numpy.array_str(paso39[0])+str("%")
print str("MANO DE OBRA    : ")+ numpy.array_str(paso39[1])+str("%")
print str("USO DE MAQUINA  : ")+ numpy.array_str(paso39[2])+str("%")
print     "____________________________"
print
```

The same on windows and mac, after that i have some prints

PRINT ON MAC:

```
OXICORTE - SOLDADURA MANUAL
PASO 38 - ESTRUCTURA DE COSTOS TOTALES POR PRODUCTO [ DATOS EXPRESADOS EN PORCENTAJES DEL COSTO TOTAL DEL PRODUCTO ]

TIPO              517    525    535
_____________________________________
MATERIA PRIMA   : 76%    76%    73%
MANO DE OBRA    : 17%    17%    20%
USO DE MAQUINA  : 6%     6%     6%
_____________________________________

OXICORTE - SOLDADURA MANUAL
PASO 39 - ESTRUCTURA DE COSTOS TOTAL [ DATOS EXPRESADOS EN PORCENTAJES DE LOS COSTOS TOTALES ]

TIPO                COSTO
____________________________
MATERIA PRIMA   : 75%
MANO DE OBRA    : 17%
USO DE MAQUINA  : 6%
____________________________
```

PRINT ON WINDOWS:

```
OXICORTE - SOLDADURA MANUAL
PASO 38 - ESTRUCTURA DE COSTOS TOTALES POR PRODUCTO [ DATOS EXPRESADOS EN PORCENTAJES DEL COSTO TOTAL DEL PRODUCTO ]

TIPO              517    525    535
_____________________________________
MATERIA PRIMA   : **-2%**    **16%**    73%
MANO DE OBRA    : **-9%**    **17%**    20%
USO DE MAQUINA  : 6%     6%     6%
_____________________________________

OXICORTE - SOLDADURA MANUAL
PASO 39 - ESTRUCTURA DE COSTOS TOTAL [ DATOS EXPRESADOS EN PORCENTAJES DE LOS COSTOS TOTALES ]

TIPO                COSTO
____________________________
MATERIA PRIMA   : **-8%**
MANO DE OBRA    : **1%**
USO DE MAQUINA  : 6%
____________________________
```

**UPDATE:**

all the arrays are OK in both OS, the problem is with p161[0]/p351[0] and the other divisions, 
in MAC i get 0.76 and in Windows 0.0, and then after that when i do the *100, in windows i get -2 as output.

This example is on PASO38 MATERIA PRIMA 517.

Comment: Show us some code that gets different values on the two operating systems, please.

Comment: What are pXXX arrays? And please edit your question to add the code instead.

Comment: ready now i have uploaded all the info

Comment: @CarlosWaitforitReichmannVal Sidenote: You can ping with an `@username` the people that have commented on your post, so that they get notified that you updated the question (otherwise they will probably never notice).

Comment: @Chris now everything is ready

Comment: @mishik now everything is ready the information is above :D

Comment: Did you try printing the values `p161[0]` and `p351[0]` to check whether they are different between OSs? If not, how do you know that the difference doesn't originate *before* the code you provided?

Comment: @DavidRobinson , i have just tried, the inputs " p161,p231,p301 are OK in both SO,  the problem is with paso38517, paso 38525 and paso38535

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is with p161[0]/p351[0] and the other divisions. On the Mac I get 0.76 and on Windows 0.0.

That sounds rather like your division operator is performing floating point division on the Mac and truncating integer division on Windows. That would happen if you were running Python 3 on the Mac, and Python 2 on Windows. But the old style `print` statements suggest otherwise. It would also happen if you had executed

```
from __future__ import division
```

on the Mac but not in the Windows code.

Since you clearly want floating point division you should do one of the following, everywhere:

1. Use Python 3 where `/` always means true floating point division.
2. Use `from __future__ import division`.
3. Convert one of your operands to `float` before performing the division.